# Better way to write if statement with a lot of ||

Tags: java, if-statement

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to write an if statement with a lot of || in java.
I've given different values to alphabet letters:

```
A,O,I,B,T,S,M,N -> 1 
C,D,F,G         -> 5 
W,Y,Z,H,Q       -> 10
```

So, I want to check a given letter and if is equal with one of  the 2nd group for example to get 5.
Right now I'm checking like this:

```
String value;
if (getLetter().equals("Α")|| getLetter().equals("O") ||
    getLetter().equals("I") || getLetter().equals("B") ||
    getLetter().equals("T") || getLetter().equals("S") ||
    getLetter().equals("N") || getLetter().equals("N"))
value = "1";
```

is there a better way to do it?

Comment: put all the element(A,O,I etc) in a list and use contains method `list.contains(getLetter())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String letter = getLetter();
if ("AOIBTSMN".contains(letter)) 
    value = "1"; 
else if ("CDFG".contains(letter))
    value = "5";
else if ("WYZHQ".contains(letter))
    value = "10";
```

Not optimal, but short, clear and self-explaining.

Comment: Wow, didnt think from this angle, loving SO for this :)

Comment: I prefer this too, easy and with less code, way. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Three options:

- Use a switch statement, assuming you're using Java 7 or 8:

  ```
  switch (getLetter()) {
      case "A":
      case "O":
      case "I":
      case "B":
      ...
          value = "1";
      ...
  }
  ```
- Use three `Set<String>` objects
- (Best, IMO) Use a `Map<String, String>`

The last option would be something like:

```
// You'd presumably initialize this in one place...
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
map.put("A", "1");
map.put("O", "1");
map.put("I", "1");
...
map.put("C", "5");
map.put("D", "5");
...

String value = map.get(getLetter());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **HashMap** for your purpose.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hm.put("A",1);
hm.put("B",1);
hm.put("O",1);
hm.put("I",1);
....
hm.put("C",5);
hm.put("D",5);
...
```

While fetching you don't need an **if condition**

```
int value = hm.get("A");  // Will return 1
```